# sharepoint 2007 print

Tags: asp.net, css, printing

We have application pages in library in Sharepoint 2007. I am solving very strange issue. We are using two css files - Common.css and Print.css.

Print.css is described like this

`<link runat="server" rel="Stylesheet" id="cssPrint" type="text/css" media="print">`

We have button on the page which is calling js function window.print().
We are using IE 8.0 (which is also required for users).

On my development machine aspx page is printing as expected so it is using print.css.
But in the context of SharePoint, page is not using print.css entirely. Just some elements are styled according to this css...

Have somebody experienced same behaviour and what was the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Is this the source or the output that you see in the header when loading the page?   Do you use <Sharepoint:CssLink... and <SharePoint:CssRegistration... in the page?

Answer (score 0):

`media=print` means that these styles will only be used while printing so while in SharePoint the Print.css file is not being used.

[more about css media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html/)

the following suggestions may very well cause errors I'm not too familiar with SharePoint.

- You should either copy all of the styles from Print.css to Common.css.
- Remove the media type from Print.css and then direct your html page to use Print.css